# Cannot connect to WIFI in Lubuntu

Tags: networking, lubuntu

I have installed Lubuntu 18.04 Alternate i386 on an HP Pavilion laptop. This laptop is awful old, with only 2GB of ram and a Intel centrino duo 2 core CPU. Th problem is, that I may have misconfigured the network settings or Lu is incompatible with the laptop's hardware in some way. It sees my wifi, but will not connect to it. Firefox says, "we cant connect to the server at www..com"
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddud1.jpg

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: FYI: I would **not** have installed using *alternate* media as it was last produced in 2018-April & has received no updates; it was for boxes with 768MB of RAM or less where you box doesn't qualify.  I used boxes as old as from 2005 in QA-testing current releases (including Lubuntu 22.04 LTS) so how old is your box??  (*yeah I know i386 only laptops were sold until 2005, & low-end netbooks a few years beyond*). I'd check your system isn't *amd64* compatible but your ISO choice seems weird. Did you download it from an *official* site?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Comment: And there's no "Intel centrino duo 2 core", it's Core2Duo and they were 64-bit CPUs. Therefore, use a supported 64-bit release.